# Why isn't my intellisense listing HttpWebRequest.GetResponse method?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, httpwebrequest, getresponse

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace PhoneApp1
{
    public class ABC
    {
        //constructor

        public ABC()
        {


        }

        void abc()
        {
            String url = "";

            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetRepsonse(); //why a wiggly line here?
            XDocument Xmldoc = XDocument.Load(url);
        }
```

I do not get `GetResponse()` for the `req` object. Why would it be so?

This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse.aspx#Y1547) and many links says it should be possible.

Comment: is your namespace called `PhoneApp1` because you are developing on Windows Phone? If so, add the TAG to your question.

Comment: Added the `windows-phone-7` tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given your namespace, I assume you're writing a Windows Phone 7 app. (It would have been helpful to state this explicitly in the question.) Windows Phone 7 development uses Silverlight, which doesn't support synchronous operations like `GetResponse`. You should be looking at the [Silverlight version of MSDN for `HttpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), and looking for members with the phone icon next to them. Note that if you follow that link, you *won't* find a `GetResponse` method. You have to call `BeginGetResponse` and handle it asynchronously.

(This will all become a lot easier with the new async work being put into C# 5.)

Comment: Yes I'm using windows phone. Its tagged now. Thanks

Comment: Hi Jon, can you tell us why do one need to handle this thing asynchronously for windows phone app? Why wouldn't it allow normal synchronous operation?

Comment: @nawfal: Because people would try to do it from the UI thread, and lock up the UI. Asynchronous operation is going to be the norm for Windows 8 Metro apps too.